# What does the selfCollide tag do in URDF?

Tags: gazebo, simulation, urdf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm unable to find the specifications on tags.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199854/what-does-the-selfcollide-tag-do-in-urdf?/) by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 644 on 2014-12-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As per written in gazebo tutorial,If the tag is set to true ,the link can collide with other links in the model. You can use this link as reference [gazebo Elements For Links](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_urdf&cat=connect_ros)

---

Originally posted by [SVS](https://answers.ros.org/users/19399/svs/) with karma: 233 on 2014-12-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1